# Raindrops Differential Equations Demo

Tags: tensorflow

When I write all the code [here](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/pdes/index.md) to a `.py` file, and then run it, I get the following output:

```
can't determine number of CPU cores: assuming 4
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op         parallelism threads: 4
can't determine number of CPU cores: assuming 4
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op     parallelism threads: 4
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
```

However, it doesn't actually display an image. How can I see the actual images?

Answer (score 2):

This code in this tutorial was designed for pasting into IPython. If you run it in a notebook the `<IPython.core.display.Image object>` strings will be replaced with an image of the current state of the simulation.

An alternative would be to generate image files that contain the same data. For example, you could replace the following code:

```
f = StringIO()
PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))
```

...with some code that writes the image to the file:

```
with open("/tmp/image.jpg", "w") as f:
  PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, "jpeg")
```

...and then open the file `/tmp/image.jpg` in your favorite image viewer.